# Element in TableViewCell has multiple reference

Tags: ios, swift

I have a TableView in which I load custom cells.
In a custom cell there is a textfield which while tableview populates itself loads a custom dial pad close itself.
This floating numeric keyboard during its initialization it's passed the textfield element. But anytime I pressed a button in the numeric keyboard the text field does not change (this happens only in table view cells).

So recap:

UICellView -> with inside -> UITextField
CustomDialPad (UIView) is initialized while UICellView is loaded by its UITableView
During CustomDialPad inizialization to a method of its class is passed the UITextField

When I press one of the buttons in the CustomDialPad the UITextField does not modify itself.

So I printed in 3 different phase the dump of the UITextField element.

**Phase 1 Result - Dump of the UITextField while the cell is loading:**

```
▿ Optional(<UITextField: 0x7fa83c0cd200; frame = (358 6; 104 30); text = '103.12'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x60c000229ae0>>)
  - some: <UITextField: 0x7fa83c0cd200; frame = (358 6; 104 30); text = '103.12'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x60c000229ae0>> #0
    - super: UIControl
      - super: UIView
        - super: UIResponder
          - super: NSObject
```

**Phase 2 Result - Dump of the UITextField while it load the CustomDialPad:**

```
- <UITextField: 0x7fa83c0cd200; frame = (358 6; 104 30); text = '103.12'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60c00005d190>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60c000229ae0>> #0
  - super: UIControl
    - super: UIView
      - super: UIResponder
        - super: NSObject
▿ Optional(<UITextField: 0x7fa83c096a00; frame = (358 6; 104 30); text = '103.12'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x60c00022b8a0>>)
  - some: <UITextField: 0x7fa83c096a00; frame = (358 6; 104 30); text = '103.12'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x60c00022b8a0>> #0
    - super: UIControl
      - super: UIView
        - super: UIResponder
          - super: NSObject
```

**Phase 3 Result - Dump of the UITextField while a button of the CUstomDialPad is pushed**

```
▿ Optional(<UITextField: 0x7fa83c0cd200; frame = (358 6; 104 30); text = '103.12'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60c00005d190>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60c000229ae0>>)
  - some: <UITextField: 0x7fa83c0cd200; frame = (358 6; 104 30); text = '103.12'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60c00005d190>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60c000229ae0>> #0
    - super: UIControl
      - super: UIView
        - super: UIResponder
          - super: NSObject
```

As you can see here are the reference in the 3 different phases:

```
Phase 1: Optional(UITextField: 0x7fa83c0cd200)
Phase 2: UITextField: 0x7fa83c0cd200
         Optional(UITextField: 0x7fa83c096a00)
Phase 3: Optional(UITextField: 0x7fa83c0cd200)
```

Why do I have 2 different references in phase 2?
Could it be that the reason why values in UITextFields don't change during CustomDialPad's buttons pushing?
How can I retrieve the element with the reference same in the other phases in Phase 2?

Regards,
Matteo

Helping Code:

Custom UIView class NumbersPadView

```
class NumbersPadView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var number1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var number2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var number3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var number4: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var number5: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var number6: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var number7: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var number8: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var number9: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var zero: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var dot: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var delete: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var done: UIButton!

    var connectedTextField: UITextField!
    var isFirstInput = true

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }

    func showMyself(showing: UIView, element: UITextField) {
        self.connectedTextField = element
        self.connectedTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.isFirstInput = true
        self.connectedTextField.selectedTextRange = self.connectedTextField.textRange(from: self.connectedTextField.beginningOfDocument, to: self.connectedTextField.endOfDocument)
        self.alpha = 0.0
        let frame = showing.convert(self.connectedTextField.frame, from:self.connectedTextField.superview)
        self.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(Double(frame.origin.x) - Double(self.frame.width) - 2)
        self.frame.origin.y = CGFloat((Double(frame.origin.y) + Double(element.frame.height) / 2) - Double(self.frame.height) / 2)

        if self.superview == nil {
            showing.addSubview(self)
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        })
        dump(self.connectedTextField) //Phase 2
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (isFirstInput) {
            self.connectedTextField.text = ""
        }
        self.isFirstInput = false
        switch sender.tag {
        case 10: //zero
            self.connectedTextField.text = self.connectedTextField.text! + "0"
            break
        case 12: //back
            if self.connectedTextField.text != "" {
                var tmpText = self.connectedTextField.text
                tmpText = tmpText?.substr(start: 1, length: (tmpText?.length)! - 1)
                self.connectedTextField.text = tmpText
                if tmpText == "." {
                    tmpText = tmpText?.substr(start: 1, length: (tmpText?.length)! - 1)
                    self.connectedTextField.text = tmpText
                }
            }
            break
        case 13:
            if self.connectedTextField.text != "" && self.connectedTextField.text?.range(of:".") == nil {
                self.connectedTextField.text = self.connectedTextField.text! + "."
            }
            break
        default:
            self.connectedTextField.text = self.connectedTextField.text! + String(sender.tag)
            break
        }
        self.connectedTextField.selectedTextRange = self.connectedTextField.textRange(from: self.connectedTextField.endOfDocument, to: self.connectedTextField.endOfDocument)
        dump(self.connectedTextField) //Phase 3
    }

    @IBAction func donePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let tmpDoubleValue = self.connectedTextField.text?.getDouble()
        self.connectedTextField.text = tmpDoubleValue?.toString(2)
        self.connectedTextField.selectedTextRange = self.connectedTextField.textRange(from: self.connectedTextField.endOfDocument, to: self.connectedTextField.endOfDocument)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
        })
        self.connectedTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

Populating UITableViewCell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let tmpCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ItemCellNew", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ItemCellNew
            tmpCell.setCell(item: items[indexPath.row])
            tmpCell.POSItemsFunctionsDelegate = self
            if self.idOrder != "" {
                tmpCell.setOrderCell()
            }
            dump(tmpCell.amountInput) // Phase 1
            return tmpCell
        }
```

Cell Method setCell()

```
func setCell(item: itemStruct) {
        if item.realQty < item.qty {
            self.bkgView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "NO_QUANTITY")
        }
        self.title.text = item.title
        self.brand.text = item.brand
        self.qty.text = String(item.qty)
        self.amountInput.text = String(item.prc)
        self.subTotal.text = String(item.prc * Double(item.qty))
        self.amountInput.setShowingNumberPad()
    }
```

Entension for UITextField:

```
func setShowingNumberPad() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didEditingBegin(_:)), for: .editingDidBegin)
    }

    @objc func didEditingBegin(_ sender:UITextField) {
        var customKeyboard: NumbersPadView!
        let views = sender.parentViewController?.view.subviews.filter{$0 is NumbersPadView}
        if views?.count == 0 {
            customKeyboard = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NumbersPadView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? NumbersPadView)!
        } else {
            customKeyboard = views?.first as! NumbersPadView
        }
        customKeyboard.showMyself(showing: (self.parentViewController?.view)!, element: sender as UITextField)
    }
```

Comment: Some code might help understand the problem.

Comment: @Adeel there you go man

Comment: what does the __dump__ method do?

Comment: @Adeel prints on the log the reference of the object in that case (Phase 1, Phase 2 and Phase 3 results of this post)

Comment: Maybe not relevant. When you show the keypad you add it as a subview of the showing view and in done button action you are not removing it from the superview.

Comment: Your code seems okay. Need to debug it to trace the problem. Can you create a github repo of your project and share the code?

Comment: @Adeel can you understand why the dump in phase 2 there are 2 references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem by modifing the item contained in the items array corresponding to the indexPath of the selected cell and reloading the data inside the tableview.

You can't access directly to input field located inside cells.